# Determine whether a name is a Workgroup or a Domain in a Windows forest

Tags: winapi, network-programming, windows-networking

My app is running on client's network, where they have a windows forest with multiple `Domains` and `Workgroups`. We're using `NetServerEnum` function, with the flag `SV_TYPE_DOMAIN_ENUM`, for enumerating all of these "sub-networks" - domains and workgroups.

After that, we need to determine for each name whether it's a `WORKGROUP` or a `DOMAIN`.

One option I had is using `DsGetDcName`, knowing it should fail for a workgroup, but I'm quite sure there are better ways.